# Non changing vector components within a For Loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, indexing

Given the following code:

```
t = -5:.1:5;
w = pi;
x = zeros(101,1);
Xt = zeros(101,1);

for i = 1 : 101;
   x = exp((-3*t)+(-1i*w*t));
   Xt = trapz(t, x);
end

disp (length(x))
disp (length(Xt))
disp (Xt)
```

The values of Xt do not change, which is a problem.
How should this be coded in order for Xt to change when x is changed?

*Side note:*

```
Xt(i) = trapz(t,x);
```

Reduces the vector from length 101 to length 1 and therefore cannot be used.

Comment: The for loop is iterating through variable `i = 1:101`, yet you never use the variable `i` in the `exp` expression. Instead you are using `-1i` which is an imaginary number (maybe this is on purpose), but still, the expression will never change since there is no dependence on your loop variable `i`.

Comment: Clarification: I am trying to use the `-1i` as an imaginary number. The variable that is supposed to change is `t`. The reason I am using `i` is because of an error that occurs when referencing the zero value at in the middle of the set. `Xt(abs(i))` would be great but I as of yet don't know how to avoid the error that occurs at zero.

Comment: To avoid indices i and j, it is common practice to use ii and jj instead. In fact, some people always use  double-letter names for their loop variables only, e.g. aa, bb, ii, jj, ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure if this is what you wanted. anyways while working on imaginary numbers it is always a good idea to not use i and j as common variables, just to avoid confusion (IMO)

```
xt = zeros(101,1);
x = exp((-3.*t)+(-1i*w.*t));

for k=2:101
    xt(k)=trapz(t(1:k),x(1:k));
end
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, could you explain why k starts at 2?

Comment: that is because here we are numerically integrating over a function which is defined over a finite interval or a finite number of points. consider a curve defined by 3 points - f0,f1,f2 at time t0,t1,t2. when we are integrating numerically, area under the curve is defined discretely by 2 small areas under the two segments (t0,f0 and t1,f1) and (t1,f1 and t2,f2). similarly for differentiation, it is two slopes between 2 segments (t0,f0 and t1,f1) and (t1,f1 and t2,f2). either way, we are losing a point, since integral and differential are now ideally defined at (t0+t1)/2 and (t1+t2)/2.

Comment: so people commonly assume first point to be zero (which i have done) if grid steps (dt) are small.

Comment: alternatively, this is the real thing - for k=2:101 xt(k)=xt(k-1) + 0.5*dt*(x(k)+x(k-1)); end  % this i think is the actual trapezoidal rule